# ^@ added when calling system in cmd.exe

Tags: vimscript, gvim

Here is an excerpt of my `vimrc`

```
let g:conda_activate = 'myenv'

function Condaenv(env)
    return trim(system("conda activate ". a:env. " && call echo %CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%"))
endfunction

augroup Condaenvget
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * let g:conda_env = Condaenv(g:conda_activate)
augroup END

let g:airline_section_b = airline#section#create(['(%{g:conda_env})'])
```

As you see, I am using `vim_airline` plugin to manage the statusline but I don't think this is relevant to my problem that I am going to explain next.

I get the error `Could not find conda environment myenv^@` on my status line.
This is an error that you get when you run `conda activate env` from `cmd.exe` but `env` does not exist.

Therefore, I think the issue is in the function `Condaenv`.
It looks like that the value of the variable `a:env` is `'myenv^@'` instead of `'myenv'`.
I tried to use   `trim(system("conda activate ". trim(a:env). " && call echo %CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%"))` but with no success.
I am running `gvim 9.0` on `Windows10` if it may help.

Any hints?

Comment: To some extent. It was actually me asking that question and the problem was solved using trim(system("conda activate ". a:env. " && call echo %CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%")). 
Now, it is few days that this solution is not working any longer (I don’t know for what misterious reason given that I havent touched the vimrc since then), and the problem now is not in the returned string by trim but in the argument a:env inside system().

Comment: I know, that's why I was looking your other question up. And in the question, we discussed a few other ways to solve the way to get rid of the `^M` (e.g. using `systemlist()`). And I still think, it does not make to have this command executed very often (each the statusline is re-evaluated). This will make your vim slow.

Comment: Yeah, in-fact I am planning to try with systemlist but I am too tired now, so I will try tomorrow morning. 
Regarding the last part I didn’t get your point last time, nor now :) the event that triggers the call to Condaenv function is VimEnter, so in my understanding it happens once. Once the variable g:conda_env is written it won’t be updated any longer. At this least this is my understanding in looking at my code. But if I misunderstood something, please explain, I am all ears :)

Comment: I have finally found some time to make some test. `systemlist` has problems too but after some troubleshooting here is what I found: if I run :`!conda list --envs` from vim I get what you see from the first picture [here](https://imgur.com/a/FQsajsy), which looks weird. By running the command `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (conda info --envs)` after having opened `cmd.exe` in Windows, I get the (correct) second picture of the link I provided above. It looks like that something goes wrong when calling `cmd.exe` commands from Vim by using `:!`.

Comment: Given that the problem seems different, I am closing this question and I opened another one here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39304/different-behavior-when-running-commands-in-cmd-exe-and-in-vim-through